# Incompatible pointer types error LHSprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

Getting a Incompatible pointer types initializing 'LHSprite *' with an expression of type 'SkNode*'
in this line of code.

```
LHSprite* player = [self childNodeWithName:@"Explosion"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty much self explanatory. `[self childNodeWithName:@"Explosion"]` returns an object of type `SkNode`, and you're trying to jam it into an object of type `LHSprite`.

Comment: What would be the best approach to correcting that? The object I am trying to call is a animated sprite.

Comment: Try casting the result of the operation and see if that works, it probably will: LHSprite *player = (LHSprite *)[self childNodeWithName:@"Explosion"];

Comment: Thank You I was using a different form of that